# Loop through directory, find lines with 2 string patterns, and print to columns in data.frame

Tags: r, string, file, loops

I have approximately 40000 .txt files in nested directories which contain lines of hardware configuration settings.

```
* System# 5 Model 295 Date: Tue Dec 17 12:00:07 2013   (file format version 1.0)

[System_Settings]
Time_Reference=COMPUTER
AutoReset_Enable=0
AutoReset_Hour=12

[Echo_Selection]
Tag_Encoding=0
PW_Filter=1.0
Use_3dB_Criteria=1
Use_6dB_Criteria=0
Use_12dB_Criteria=0
Min_3dB_Samples=3
Max_3dB_Samples=23
Min_6dB_Samples=6
Max_6dB_Samples=24
Min_12dB_Samples=12
Max_12dB_Samples=36
SearchWnd_Samples=30
Use_ExcludeWnd=0
ExcludeWnd_Samples=15

[Total_Objects]
Hydrophones=1

[Hydrophone_1]
Number=5
Channel=1
State=RECEIVE
Gain=42
Min_Volts=0.1
SNR_Threshold=3.0
SNR_Filter=1

[End_System]
System=103

[Histogram]
Min_TagBinRange=24
Max_TagBinRange=24

[SubCode]
Search_BinRange=24

[AutoTracking]
Min_Pings=2
Max_PingGap=10
Max_SwimSpeed=1.000000
```

I'd like to extract 3 settings from each file by matching the line of each setting to a text pattern:

```
"Number=*"
"Min_Pings=*"
"Max_PingGap=*"
```

and place the numeric value which comes after the "=" into a data frame.

To start, I attempted to run a loop to extract the entire line string for two of the settings...and this produced something very large that was not at all what I intended...it looked like a list of 2x2 matrices?

I'm still getting into R and sometimes struggle pulling concepts from multiple stack exchanges.  I've found a bunch of looping and appending solutions, but none really do what I'm doing.

Eventually I'd like to have 3 columns with numeric values:

```
Number Min_Pings Max_PingGap
  5       2           4
  3       5          10


#My attempt
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(readr)

files <- list.files(path="PATH", pattern="*.tat", full.names=TRUE, recursive = T) #construct the list of all file names

df <- data.frame(x = character(),y = character(), stringsAsFactors = F) #construct a dataframe

names(df) <- c("MinPing","PingGap")#Add column names

#loop
pings <- sapply(files, function(x) {
  minping <- read_lines(file = x, 
                        skip = c(grep("Min_Pings=",
                                      readLines(x))-1), 
                        n_max = 1 ) #Read the line from each file where "Min_Pings=" is found
  pinggap <- read_lines(file = x, 
                         skip = c(grep("Max_PingGap=",
                                       readLines(x))-1), 
                         n_max = 1 ) #Read the line from each file where "MaxPingGap=" is found
  de <- data.frame(minping,pinggap) #store strings in dataframe
  rbind(df, setNames(de, names(df))) #bind the new dataframe to the old dataframe
})
```

Comment: It'd help if you add some small sample content from **one** of your .txt files to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that each iteration of your function references the initial empty `df` instead of redefining `df` and going from there. Does the following work for you?

```
df <- data.frame(MinPing = character(), PingGap = character(), stringsAsFactors = F) #construct a dataframe

for(i in files){
  minping <- read_lines(file = i, 
                        skip = c(grep("Min_Pings=",
                                      readLines(i))-1), 
                        n_max = 1 ) #Read the line from each file where "Min_Pings=" is found
  pinggap <- read_lines(file = i, 
                        skip = c(grep("Max_PingGap=",
                                       readLines(i))-1), 
                        n_max = 1 ) #Read the line from each file where "MaxPingGap=" is found
  de <- data.frame(minping,pinggap) #store strings in dataframe
  df <- rbind(df, setNames(de, names(df))) #bind the new dataframe to the old dataframe
}

head(df) #Take a look at the final result
```

Comment: I see!! Yes, this works! thanks so much! appreciate you!